# Find next class relative to document - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, find

Hey I'm in need of some help I have made this gallery plugin where I am now in need of a way to find the next class which called the plugin relative to the document incase the images are in different parent divs? Check the code below

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="a">
    <img class="image" src="/gallery/a.png" style="max-width:200px;max-height:200px;"/>
</div>
<div id="b">
    <img class="image" src="/gallery/b.jpg" style="max-width:200px;max-height:200px;"/>
</div>
<div id="c">
    <img class="image" src="/gallery/c.jpg" style="max-width:200px;max-height:200px;"/>
</div>


// jQuery
$('.image').imageGallery();

var next = $(self).next().attr("src"); // "Self" being the current image its on
```

The above is only viable if all the images are sitting in the same parent div but I would like to be able to get all images with the same class relative to the body.

Non working example:

```
$("body").find(self).next()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store all the images on which you apply `.imageGallery();` once, and then reuse that list:

```
var images = $('.image');
images.imageGallery();

var next = images.eq( images.index(self) + 1 );
```

Comment: +1 Nice. But it will give an `undefined` error, if no next image is present. Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fTuf2/).

Comment: You have now brought my gallery to life!!

Comment: Is there anyways to reference self against the images array to get its position?

Comment: @JustinJohn: That's no error, that's expected. There is no element after the third image, and an empty selection returns `undefined` attributes. For a rotating manner, you could use `modulo images.length`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

```
var images = $("body").find("img");
var next = images[images.index(self) + 1];
source = $(next).attr('src');
```

Comment: I am wanting to be able to search the whole document for the next $(self) as in some situations the images might be separated by multiple parents etc.

Comment: In that case you should create a reference to all the images. And just use it whenever you want to access the next image.

Answer (score 0):

You may use following code:

`$(self).parent().next().child().attr("src");`

I know this seems a long way to go but may this is helpful.